# Convert two df cols to dict on python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this df:

```
Id  count
A1    3
A2    4
A3    5
```

And I want to convert it to a dict where 'Id' is the keys and 'count' the values:

```
dict = {'A1': 3, 'A2': 4, 'A3': 5}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) here.

```
dict(zip(df['Id'],df['count']))

# {'A1': 3, 'A2': 4, 'A3': 5}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 dict(df.values)
```

will do the job.

Note that this assumes `df` has 2 "columns" i.e. those other than the index.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

```
result = dict(zip(df['Id'], df['count']))
```